# wrapping figure with latex environment in knitr/rmarkdown with hooks

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'd like to wrap figures created with knitr and rmarkdown in a "wrapfigure" environment using hooks. However, when running the minimal example below, the figure chunk only gets compiled into a markdown picture:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
![](test_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf) 
\end{wrapfigure}
```

and not the expected:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics{test_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Minimal example:

````
---
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{wrapfig}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(wrapf = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(before) {
    "\\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\\textwidth}"
  } else {
    "\\end{wrapfigure}"
  }
})
```

```{r, wrapf=TRUE}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(cars$speed, cars$dist)
```
````

Comment: Try to add `results = "asis"` to the `r` chunk.

Comment: Tried that. Same result.

Comment: @user2987808
[The answer by @MartinSchmelzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112408/10215301) would be the current best answer. This is worth trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandoc` is responsible for converting the markdown document to a TEX document. As `pandoc` doesn't touch between `\begin{…}` and `\end{…}` the markdown syntax for the image is not being converted to TEX syntax.

You could …

- Hide the plot (`fig.show = 'hide'`) and use something along the lines of `cat("\includegraphics{figure/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf}")`.
- Hide the plot as above and include some magic in the hook that saves the `cat`.
- Write RNW instead of RMD if you want PDF output.

Here's an example for option 2:

```
knit_hooks$set(wrapf = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(before) {
    return("\\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\\textwidth}")
  } else {

    output <- vector(mode = "character", length = options$fig.num + 1)

    for (i in 1:options$fig.num) {
      output[i] <- sprintf("\\includegraphics{%s}", fig_path(number = i))
    }

    output[i+1] <- "\\end{wrapfigure}"
    return(paste(output, collapse = ""))
  }
})
```

This hook can be used with `wrapf = TRUE` and `fig.show = "hide"`. (Moreover, you need to add `\usepackage{graphics}` to `header-includes`.)

But note that **I would not do it**! Too many things can go wrong in more complex settings. Think of cache, captions, labels, cache (*again!*) …

Therefore, if it is really necessary to control the typesetting of the PDF, I recommend writing RNW (option 3).