# Use of out.extra generates Package keyval Error: style undefined

Tags: pdf, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am new to R Markdown and I am trying to generate a pdf report for my class. I have a small figure that I do not want taking up so many lines and surrounded by white space, so I'd like to wrap text around it. It can be aligned left or right, it doesn't matter.

I have tried a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551312/wrap-text-around-plots-in-markdown), but

```
{r plot, out.width="4in", out.extra='style="float:right; padding:10px"',  echo=F}
knitr::include_graphics("myplot.png")
```

throws the following error:

> "! Package keyval Error: style undefined."

and the document won't compile. I have searched high and low and can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: What you found is for HTML output. For PDF output via LaTeX have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112408/8416610