# Modifying the LaTeX environment in the output hooks

Tags: r, r-markdown, hook, knitr

I want to modify the LaTeX environment for figures from `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` to `\begin{figure*}..\end{figure*}` using a custom chunk option (in this case, `fullwidth=TRUE` ) as a switch. The environment definition is provided by my LaTeX class (sn-jnl).

I came across [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67825951/how-to-customize-figure-latex-with-knitr-rmarkdown) of the hook (modified to suit my case):

```r
hook_plot_output <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("plot") 
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
    out <- hook_plot_output(x, options)
    if(!is.null(options$fullwidth) && options$fullwidth) { 
      out  <- gsub("\\begin{figure}", "\\begin{figure*}",  
             gsub("\\end{figure}", "\\end{figure*}", out, fixed=TRUE), 
             fixed=TRUE)
    }
   out
})
```

Here I am capturing the whole output of the function (`out`) and modifying it. The recommended approach [in the book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html) is to only modify the content of `x` and return the output of the function.

```r
hook_plot_output <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("plot")  # save the old hook
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
   if(!is.null(options$fullwidth) && options$fullwidth) { 
     x  <- gsub("\\begin{figure}", "\\begin{figure*}",  
              gsub("\\end{figure}", "\\end{figure*}", x, fixed=TRUE), 
              fixed=TRUE)
    }
   hook_plot_output(x, options)
})
```

Can someone explain to me why the first approach works and the second one doesn't? It has something to do with the evaluation of the captured `hook_plot_output(x, options)` in the function's environment, but I can't wrap my head around how to test the difference in behavior between the two cases.

Comment: Can't you just insert a breakpoint and knit the document from within the repl? My guess is that examining `hook_plot_output` will tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in the book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html) you mentioned, `x` means a vector of (plot) file paths. There is no LaTeX code like `\begin{figure}` in `x`. The LaTeX code is added only after the default `plot` has been applied.

In your case, you could use [the chunk option](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) `fig.env = 'figure*'`, which would be much more simpler than modifying the `plot` hook. But you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, and I don't know which type of **knitr** document you were working on, so I'm not entirely sure if `fig.env` would work in your case. If it's an `Rnw` document, this option will work. If it's `Rmd`, you may need a chunk option `out.extra = ''`.